# How to make array of characters?

Tags: c

I am trying to make an array of character but I must not be doing this correctly I keep getting the warning message:

warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

I want to make an array that is 8 columns by 4 rows but when I step through the array the compiler just gives me an array of 8 strings of characters here is my code:

```
// Array of 8 columns by 4 rows  
char GameBoardDisplay[8][4];
// 4x4 matrix that is zero filled for the moment
int GameBoardTrack [4][4];


           //Steps through the matrix one by one and places characters in array
           for ( rowtrack = 0, rowtrack2 = 0 ; rowtrack != 4 ; rowtrack++, rowtrack2++){
            for (coltrack = 0, coltrack2= 0 ; coltrack !=4 ; ++coltrack){
               if(!GameBoardTrack[rowtrack][coltrack]){

                       GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = '_';
                       ++coltrack2;

                   if (coltrack == 3){
                       GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = '\n';
                   }
                   else
                       {
                       GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = ' ';
                      ++coltrack2
               }
           }
       }
```

Am I thinking of char GameBoardDisplay[8][4] the wrong way? I see it as 32 spots to place a character that I can go back and rewrite but for some reason it only makes an array of 8 strings.

Comment: `"_"` is a string, not a character.  You want `'_'`.

Comment: You must read a basic language guide/tutorial before asking low-quality questions like this. This is too basic and it shows that you haven't made *any* effort understanding the language, not even the syntax.

Comment: I'll do what I want H2CO3. Snoody replies like this are not appreciated so please keep them to yourself. 

Thank you Oli for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"_"` is a string, formed by the characters `'_'` and `'\0'`. You want a character:

```
GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = '_';
```

The same applies to:

```
GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = '\n';
```

And:

```
GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = ' ';
```

Here are the syntaxes of a *character constant* and a *string litteral*.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.4.4.4 Character constants
>
> ```
> character-constant: ' c-char-sequence '
> ```
>
> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.4.5 String literals
>
> ```
> string-literal: encoding-prefixopt " s-char-sequenceopt "
> ```

Comment: I figured it out thank you for the help I also had the rows and columns mixed up. I had to be a [4][8].

Answer (score 1):

`"_"`, `"\n"` and everything enclosed in double quotes is a C string literal, and it's of type `const char[]`. To enter single *characters*, use single quotes/apostrophes, like this:

```
GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = '_';
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the answers here about "a" being a string and 'a' being a character and all (which you should change as well), another problem (which is the likely cause of the "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast") is that you've **redeclared the variable GameBoardDisplay as 2D integer array** right after you declared it as a 2D char array.

You could try,

```
char GameBoardDisplay[8][4];
// 4x4 matrix that is zero filled for the moment
//int GameBoardDisplay [4][4];


           //Steps through the matrix one by one and places characters in array
           for ( rowtrack = 0, rowtrack2 = 0 ; rowtrack != 4 ; rowtrack++, rowtrack2++){
            for (coltrack = 0, coltrack2= 0 ; coltrack !=4 ; ++coltrack){
               if(!GameBoardTrack[rowtrack][coltrack]){

                       GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = '_';
                       ++coltrack2;

                   if (coltrack == 3){
                       GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = '\n';
                   }
                   else
                       {
                       GameBoardDisplay[rowtrack2][coltrack2] = ' ';
                      ++coltrack2
               }
           }
       }
```